# Composing beam splitters

Tags: information-theory, unitarity, quantum-optics

Let $a, b$ and $c$ be independent modes in a system $S$ and in environments $E_1$, $E_2$ respectively. Suppose $a$ goes through a beam-splitter characterized by a parameter $\theta$ coupling it to mode $b$, so that first this first interaction we may write the unitary
$$U_\theta = \exp(i\theta(a^\dagger b + b^\dagger a)) $$
(I'm forgetting about relative phases, global signs and what-not; this should work for any kind of beam splitter, polarizing or otherwise).

Now suppose that immediately after the action $U_\theta$, the system modes (which evolved as $a'=U_\theta^\dagger aU_\theta$) go into another beam splitter with parameter $\eta$, this time coupling $S$ to the mode $c$ in $E_2$: this time, the interaction may be described by another unitary of the form
$$U_\eta= \exp(i\eta(a'^\dagger c + c^\dagger a')). $$
Intuitively, if we compose the two transformation we should get a single unitary $U_{f(\theta, \eta)}=U_\eta$ parametrized by some function $f$ of the original parameters, acting on  the mode $a$ and the tensor product $b\otimes c$. However, since the exponents of $U_\theta$ and $U_\eta$ do not commute, I'm not finding a straightforward way to derive the explicit expression for $U_{f(\theta, \eta)}$. Can someone provide an answer?

Comment: Assuming the modes are isomorphic to a qubit, the operations should be analogous to 3d rotations of the Bloch sphere. Rotations compose in a complicated way if you don't have the right representation (e.g. axis angle or Euler angles instead of quaternion or matrix representations). I'd suggest trying to get a 2x2 unitary matrix representation of your operations. Do specific examples with specific numbers instead of general ones to start.

Comment: @CraigGidney I don't see at all why the modes would be isomorphic to qubits. If you do the Schwinger mapping you can talk about "rotations" for two modes, but that's not the same as having a qubit. Regardless, the third mode requires SU(3). What you probably meant is that the action on the vector of creation (or annihilation) operators is the composition of two 3d rotations about different axes - nothing about qubits, but agreed that you can talk about 3d rotations using a 2x2 unitary matrix representation

Comment: @CraigGidney I even take the final part back: the 3x3 matrices acting on the vector of creation or annihilation operators isn't necessarily real, so it does not correspond to a rotation matrix. The composition of two SU(3) operations is even more complicated than the composition of two rotations (ie two SO(3) operations or you can use two SU(2) operations as per the suggestion with 2x2 matrices). There is a subspace where they will be the same, but this is not it (different phases are required to make the rotation matrices real)

Comment: @CraigGidney I made the matrices explicit in my answer to the cross-posted question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/794184/291677